# Where to distribute free math ed materials for informal settings?

Tags: primary-education

I am a psychologist studying mathematical thinking and learning and I have been organizing a monthly math night at a local library. Each math night consists of a short presentation followed by several fun hands-on activities relating to a math topic such as tessellation, probability, game theory, etc.

Having done this for some time, I now have numerous sets of materials that I've designed and could potentially be used by other people. The materials are slides to be used for presentations, scripts that tell the organizer what materials are needed and how to run the activities, and in some cases, handouts to be printed and used in the activities.

**What would be some good channels or platforms for me to release these materials for free use by others?**

Comment: If this is in the U.S. then I recommend you also ask this in an appropriate [MAA Connect](https://www.maa.org/member-communities/maa-connect) community. If you're not an MAA member, then maybe ask a colleague or friend who is a member to post this for you. Similarly for [NCTM](https://www.nctm.org/), although I'm less familiar with NCTM regarding their possible email listserv groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you post them **here**.

On StackExchange sites, [it's totally acceptable to ask a question and then answer it yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/164838), even posting multiple answers.

Just write the question that you think someone might Google later when trying to find your materials, then answer it multiple times with the various materials. Or, if you have several categories, you could ask multiple questions and answer them all, but I'd recommend keeping it to as few questions as possible.

The possible downside is that StackExchange doesn't really "host" worksheets and printouts, but if you can post them somewhere else like Google Drive and reference them here, this place is designed well to help others find your questions and answers over the medium-to-long-term.

As an added bonus, others might post more materials as replies!